# Using BeginForm() To Upload File and passing Att' (ASP-MVC 4)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, html.beginform

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 Project, and I need to be able to upload a file or files to save them and make an instance of that file or files( so I will be able to keep information about them).

In order to implement this I have two classes inside of 'Models':

**1. UploadFile:** (this class will represent a single file)

```
       public class UploadFile
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }

        public string Status { get; set; }

        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    }
```

**2. Scan:** (this class will represent a one upload of file or files)

```
public class Scan
{

    public IEnumerable<UploadFile> Files { get; set; }

    public long ContentLength()
    {
        long size = 0;
        foreach (UploadFile f  in Files)
        {
            size =+ f.File.ContentLength;
        }
        return size;
    }
}
```

also I have one controller **'HomeController.cs"**, and I have this action in there:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Scan scan)
    {

            if (scan.ContentLength() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var s in scan.Files)
                {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(s.File.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadFiles"), fileName);
                s.File.SaveAs(path);
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

And the View is **'index.cshtml'**, and this is the begin.form:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>File:</td>
                    <td><input type="file" name="Scan" id="Scan" multiple /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        }
            </div>
```

**My Main Goal:** upload a file/files (save them at "~/Content/UploadFiles") and during this process to create an instance of UploadFile and Scan (Scan hold a collection of UploadFile), so i can represent them to the user and keep tracking and catalog them in my DB.

**My problem** is that "scan" is null in 'homecontroller.cs' how can i pass argument so i could create instances of the two classes and still upload the file ?

As you may notice i'm new at MVC design-structure, so if i'm missing a point or two of MVC because of my implement let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: how about a parallel.foreach? never used it but seems like a good candidate to me

Comment: The problem is How can I get the information about the file from the beginform to the HTTP-POST function in the controller ?

Comment: s.File has all the information needed for the file. You can just grab details from that one.

Comment: Yeah but there is a problem with that, I never get to the part of the foreach, when it reach the if-statement its breaks because 'scan' is null, what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Now it makes sense why your scan object null. Your scan object dont have model binding with the view. So you need to do that. Wihtout model binding biew dont know how send scan object which is required. FYI you cant bind uploaded file with a model property but the file will always be available in httpcontext. When once you receive a initilized scan object then just assign file to scan object files. This should solve the issue

Comment: Wow...very complicated, so if I deals with files(upload to my server through the site) i need to do model binding or it wont help me achive my goal ?  just use httpcontext ?
i'll read now about the httpcontext so i will have a better understanding of what your saying..

Comment: Its not complicated. May be i have explained wrong. You have view for uploading files. So the only thing you need to do is pass a new scan() when you do the get action for view. Then the rest will be handled by mvc by default. When you post the form to your post method mvc will send a intantiated scan object to the post. This is just to ensure that u dont get a null one. Once you have an intantiated object the rest should be easy. Just assign value to the property of scan object. Or just add a null check for scan object if its not there create a new one